# What is the best approach to create an object inside abstract class?

Tags: java, oop

What is the best approach to build color and location objects inside an abstract class, and **why**?

#### Approach 1

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private int vehicleId;
    private Color color; // color Object
    private Location location; // location Object

    public Vehicle() {
        color = new Color();
        location = new Location();
    }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private String type;

    public Car() {
        super();    
    }
}
```

#### Approach 2

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private int vehicleId;
    protected Color color; // color Object
    protected Location location; // location Object

    public Vehicle(){}
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private String type;

    public Car(){
        super();
        super.location = new Location();
        super.color = new Color();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two aproaches is that the first one *instantiates its state in the abstract class*. So every inheritor will inherit that state (though cannot access it since its `private` and not `protected`).

In the second approach the state of the object is getting *initialized inside the inheritor's constructor* and probably you **were forced** to declare `color` and `location` as `protected` since you would not be able to access that state.

Which approach is better? It depends... If you want every child to inherit a common state, the first one. If you want every child to define its own state, the second.